# Compiling tesseract on Windows using Cygwin GCC

Tags: c++, tesseract

Getting below error while compiling tesseract source on Windows using Cygwin GCC:

> -MT"training/commontraining.d" -o "training/commontraining.o" "../training/commontraining.cpp"
>   ../training/commontraining.cpp:17:30: fatal error: **base/init_google.h**: No such file or directory

Please help me find which library provides the `init_google.h` header file.

Comment: Here's a blog post on [how to build tesseract on Windows/Cygwin](http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-cygwin.html). I hope it helps.